# Дерево в базе данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, дерево

Как правильно организовать структуру репостов записей?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самая очевидная структура, такая:

```
post_id  |  parent_post  |  text
1        |  NULL         |  ...
2        |  1            |  ...
3        |  2            |  ...
4        |  2            |  ...
5        |  1            |  ...
6        |  3            |  ...
7        |  2            |  ...
```

но, чтобы выбрать все репосты одной записи надо написать огромный запрос, который вполне может положить сервер.

возможно есть паттерн для плоской структуры?

Comment: А зачем выбирать все репосты одной записи? Как правило, надо знать только их кол-во. А в ленте надо выбрать в обратной сторону - если автор ленты сделал репост с комментарием, то надо всего-лишь выбрать все родительские репосты с их комментариями, и вложить друг в друга. Как правило, это максимум 5 уровней. Это если у вас репосты работают как в Tumblr, например.

Comment: @ArturUdod, я имел ввиду дерево репостов одной записи. в такой структуре придется делать `select` по каждому `parent_post` и если их будет много, то соотв. будет очень много запросов к бд

Comment: Виталий, я понял, только вот вопрос: что это за сценарий такой? Дерево репостов одной записи может содержать миллионы постов, как Вы это собираетесь показывать на UI? Я не могу себе представить такой пользовательский сценарий

Comment: Если надо показать кто тебя репостил и с какими комментариями, то выбирайте сначала первые X записей первого уровня с сортировкой по дате. При нажатии на стрелку вправо, загружаются следующие X записей. При клике на сам репост, подгружается дальше его дерево по тому же принципу. В общем, юзер-сценарий может быть любой, главное то, что ну никак не получится показать сразу все репосты, а значит и загружать все сразу не надо.

Comment: А если речь идет о суммарном кол-ве репостов, то, во-первых запросы в БД на кол-во выполняются гораздо быстрее, во-вторых, можно сделать отдельную таблицу-счетчик.

Comment: @ArturUdod, в вк показывается сразу все дерево

Comment: Понимаю, это мб звучит странно, но я не в курсе, как в VK =) но! Вы хотите сказать, что там сразу показано все дерево в развернутом состоянии? Не верю, т.к. должны быть кнопки для разворачивания след. уровня, вот на них и должна происходить динамическая подгрузка, то же самое касается скроллинга вниз

Comment: И вообще, Вы про репосты или по комментарии?

Comment: @ArturUdod, про репосты. с комментариями все проще... а вк вот так сделано http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1457794013.png

Comment: мне кажется можно просто хранить путь репостов, типа `repost_path -> 3.2.1` и тогда можно достать пост и вторым запросом все дерево репостов

Comment: @ВиталийЛеонов Я кстати не понял, почему вы считаете что для каждого уровня придется писать отдельный запрос ? Если делать систему на любой боле менее вменяемой СУБД, кроме MySQL, то древовидный запрос пишется очень просто и дерево любой вложенности спокойно выберет один запрос, по времени выполнения он будет не намного больше, чем линейная выборка такого количества записей по индексу.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет действительно об дереве (так как на рисунке скорее граф, хотя по тексту у вас дерево), то вам может подойти паттерн Вложенные Множества (Nested Sets). Каждый пост вы снабжаете левой и правой границей и нумеруете все подчиненные листья дерева таким образом, чтобы левая граница репоста всегда была больше родительского поста, а правая граница, наоборот - всегда меньше.

```
post_id  |  lft  |  rth
1        |  1    |  14
2        |  2    |  11
3        |  3    |  6
6        |  4    |  5
4        |  7    |  8
7        |  9    |  10
5        |  12   |  13

1     1 <-------------------------------------------> 14
2       2 <----------------------------> 11
3         3 <-----> 6
6           4 <-> 5
4                     7 <-> 8
7                              9 <-> 10
5                                           12 <-> 13
```

Таким образом, чтобы выбрать все репосты какого поста, нужно выбрать посты, чьи левые и правые границы находятся между левыми и правыми границами корневого поста. Проблема этого паттерна в сложности вставки. Однако, он самый быстрый в плане извлечения, а главное подсчета количества репостов. Разделите правую границу корня 14 на два и получите количество постов 7 (это правда работает, если нумерация сплошная). Еще одно свойство - удаление части постов не требует перенумерации, так как границы оставшихся репостов по прежнему входят в множество исходного поста.

Comment: я рассматривал этот вариант, но, на сколько я понял, он рассчитывает что на потомка ссылается только один родитель. а как быть когда одну запись репостили несколько раз

Comment: Не совсем понятно, обычно потомок ссылается на родителя. У нас есть исходный пост, который репостят 20 человек. Исходный пост - родитель, 20 репостов - потомки, и они спокойно размещаются между левой и правой границей родительского поста. Обратите внимание на 2 пост с границами 2 - 11, у него 3 непосредственных репоста: 3-6, 7-8, 8-10, все они расположено между 2 и 11. Или у поста может быть несколько родителей? Тогда мы имеем дело с графом.

Comment: на рисунке дерево (которое, впрочем, тоже является графом), просто "вверх ногами"

Comment: Ага, но если это дерево, даже если вверх ногами, можно воспользоваться паттерном Вложенные Множества, если граф, лучше будет воспользоваться паттерном Список Соседства.

Comment: мое мнение, что нужно просто организовать порционную динамическую загрузку данных, и можно обойтись без дополнительной сложности.

Comment: @cheops, как одно подмножество может входить сразу в несколько множеств? точнее так может быть но выбрать правильное дерево будет невозможно

Comment: Если это дерево, а не граф, вы всегда сможете его представить вложенными множествами (корень - самое большое множество, листья - самые маленькие). Репосты насколько я понимаю не могут быть из двух источников? Поэтому у вас вроде должно быть чистое дерево, даже если один человек репостит разные посты с одним и тем же содержимым - источники у него разные.

Comment: @cheops, я чего то не понимаю... вот такая стркутура https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3yv2hhmca3umxa/Untitled%20Diagram.png?dl=0 можно сохранить нормальные границы для множеств только если при добавлении искать максимальное и минимальное значения уже используемых границ. а проще хранить полный путь для дерева в отдельном поле?

Comment: Паттерн перечисления путей? Вам будет очень сложно им оперировать, если вы захотите что-то вставить, а вставлять вам придется часто, если вы хотите следить за репостами в динамике, а на просто снять один  раз состояние и его анализировать. Тогда уж лучше используйте таблицу замыканий, когда вы для каждого поста храните связь со всеми репостами, на каком бы глубоком уровне вложения они не находились. Таблица будет очень большой, но если её проиндексировать можно будет оперировать. Но вообще проблем со вложенным множеством у вас не должно быть.

Comment: Просто нужно нумеровать начиная с каждого корня, у вас их на рисунке сейчас два. Проще всего это конечно на рисунке рассмотреть бы http://vench-master.spb.ru/useruploads/images/news/nst12.gif

Comment: @cheops, допустим у второго корня будут границы -4, 5, а что делать если после этого кто то добавился в первое дерево. там же будут такие же границы

Comment: При вставке границы придется пересчитывать, это накладно, заранее согласен. В перечисление путей тоже будет не просто вставлять. Самая простая вставка у Таблицы Замыканий, но она очень избыточна по хранению информации.